# El comando `code` para abrir un repositorio Git en VSC no me funciona

Tags: vscode

Estoy intentando abrir un repositorio de Git Hub em mi editor de texto VSC.

En la terminal integrada me posicione en la carpeta que quiero abrir, y pongo el siguiente comando `code ./ -r`, se supone que se tiene que abrir la carpeta en el editor de texto, pero me retorna el siguiente error:

```
code: The term 'code' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Intente con la terminal integrada de powershell, y de cmd.

Busque este error por internet pero no encontré nada claro.

Comment: hola mira este link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac te ayudara si usas mac y este si usas windows https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows

Comment: De hecho creo que la manera correcta de abrir Visual Studio Code por comandos es "code ." (lo que esta entre comillas, sin comillas obvi xd), y creo que con ese comando abre el programa no importa en que carpeta estés posicionado, lo se por que ya lo probé (desde windows).